Need help to extract this XML node - Excel connection strings in Python
I have a Python program opening up Excel (XLSX) files, and trying to find the <connection> node.
This is the full XML from the connections.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<connections 
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="xr16" 
    xmlns:xr16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2017/revision16">
    <connection 
        id="1" xr16:uid="{#####}" keepAlive="1" 
        name="Query - CargoData_small" 
        description="Connection to the 'CargoData_small' query in the workbook." 
        type="5" refreshedVersion="7" background="1">
        <dbPr connection="Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=CargoData_small;Extended Properties=&quot;&quot;" 
            command="SELECT * FROM [CargoData_small]"/>
    </connection>
</connections>

I am trying to get to find the <dbPr> node. but I am stuck on the child node of the code as shown below:
def checkfile(filename):
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(filename):
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')
        if "xl/connections.xml" in zf.namelist():
            print(filename)
            xml = zf.read('xl/connections.xml')
            root = parseString(xml)
            connections = root.getElementsByTagName('connection')
            try:
                for con in connections:
                    for child in con.childNodes:

                        # there are no 'children'
                        for children in child.childNodes:
                            dsn = children.attributes.values()[0].nodeValue
                            sql = children.attributes.values()[1].nodeValue
                            writeoutput(filename, dsn, sql )
            except:
                pass

So what happens is I get the 'child' value, but I cannot find the dbPr section.
This is what I am getting as an error:

I am using Pycharm as the IDE.
Thanks

You're missing the namespaces. The xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" in the root node means it and its descendants that don't have another namespace attached have that namespace, and as such you'll need to qualify your queries with that namespace.
A minimal example using the built-in xml.etree.ElementTree, and the data hard-coded for convenience...
data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<connections 
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="xr16" 
    xmlns:xr16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2017/revision16">
    <connection 
        id="1" xr16:uid="{#####}" keepAlive="1" 
        name="Query - CargoData_small" 
        description="Connection to the 'CargoData_small' query in the workbook." 
        type="5" refreshedVersion="7" background="1">
        <dbPr connection="Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=CargoData_small;Extended Properties=&quot;&quot;" 
            command="SELECT * FROM [CargoData_small]"/>
    </connection>
</connections>
"""

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for connection in root.findall('.//{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}connection'):
    for dbpr in connection.findall('.//{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}dbPr'):
        print(connection.attrib['name'], dbpr.attrib['connection'], dbpr.attrib['command'])

This prints out
Query - CargoData_small Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=CargoData_small;Extended Properties="" SELECT * FROM [CargoData_small]


Hi thanks for that. However, what if the namespace changes based on the Excel file I am opening? Ultimately, I want to search all XLS, XLSX and XLSM files across a network structure. I hope the namespace is the same for all flavours of Excel?

The namespace should be the same for XLSX and XLSM. XLS is not an OOXML format, you'd need an entirely different parser for it.

I suggest use lxml and xpath:
(lxml can detect the namespacemap from root - nsmap for easy find(xpath, ns).)
from lxml import etree as et
from io import BytesIO

excel_=b"""\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<connections 
    xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="xr16" 
    xmlns:xr16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2017/revision16">
    <connection 
        id="1" xr16:uid="{#####}" keepAlive="1" 
        name="Query - CargoData_small" 
        description="Connection to the 'CargoData_small' query in the workbook." 
        type="5" refreshedVersion="7" background="1">
        <dbPr connection="Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=CargoData_small;Extended Properties=&quot;&quot;" 
            command="SELECT * FROM [CargoData_small]"/>
    </connection>
</connections>"""
file = BytesIO(excel_)

root = et.parse(file).getroot()
ns = root.nsmap

# with find()
dbPr = root.find(".//dbPr", ns)

for attr in dbPr.keys():
    print(f"{attr}: {dbPr.get(attr)}")

###############################
# Alternativ via xpath directly
#
# set proxy for empty prefix
ns_map ={}
ns_map['root_ns'] = root.nsmap.get(None)

# use xpath direct to the attribute value
dbPr_con = root.xpath(".//root_ns:dbPr/@connection", namespaces=ns_map)
print("Connection:", *dbPr_con)

Output:
connection: Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=CargoData_small;Extended Properties=""
command: SELECT * FROM [CargoData_small]

Connection: Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=CargoData_small;Extended Properties=""


a simple example with beautifulsoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('xl/connections.xml') as f:
    data = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")
dbPr = soup.find('dbPr')
print(dbPr.attrs['connection'], dbPr.attrs['command'])


Thanks mate. May need this with XLS files.

@Fandango68 XLS files are proprietary binary, you cannot unzip them.
